# Using arg[v] command line arguments in a C program

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, command-line-arguments, argv

I am writing a program in C that takes several command line arguments. argv[1] will be a single character "option", either an 'a' or 'b' or 'c', each option causing the program to run differently. I would like to begin my program's main() method with an if-statement that checks the whether the option the user specified on the command line is correct, i.e. either an 'a' or 'b' or 'c', and nothing else.

My code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argv[1] != 'a' || 'b' || 'c') printf("Failure\n");
    else printf("Success\n");
}
```

When I compile this code, I am getting this warning:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

I understand that I am misusing the pointer to the char array, but I don't understand how I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression

```
if (argv[1] != 'a' || 'b' || 'c')
```

type of `argv[1]` is `char*` and type of `'a'` is `char`, which is converted to an `int` by the compiler. That explains the compiler warning message.

That line is not going to work the way you want it to. You need something like:

```
if (argv[1][0] != 'a' &&
    argv[1][0] != 'b' &&
    argv[1][0] != 'c')
{
   printf("Failure\n");
}
```

To make the program more robust, you need to first check whether there are is an argument before you check its contents.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if ( argc > 1 )
   {
      if (argv[1][0] != 'a' &&
          argv[1][0] != 'b' &&
          argv[1][0] != 'c')
      {
         printf("Failure\n");
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Success\n");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Failure\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the error, makes sense. What does the [0] part of the code do?

Comment: @user3413460, if you invoke the program with `program abcd`, then, `argv[1]` is the string `"abcd"` and `argv[1][0]` is the first character of that string, i.e. `'a'`.

Comment: I'd write it `if ( argc > 1 && strlen(argv[1]) > 0 )` to cater to `./a.out ""` cases although in these cases you could argue that argv[1][0] holds '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. First, you're comparing strings (pointers to character arrays) to characters. This is why you're getting the warning. Second, you are evaluating `'b'` and `'c'` as boolean expressions. You actually want:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (  strcmp(argv[1], "a") != 0 // strcmp returns 0 on match.
       && strcmp(argv[1], "b") != 0
       && strcmp(argv[1], "c") != 0) {
        printf("Failure\n");
    } else {
        printf("Success\n");
    }
}
```

Alternatively,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // the first character is between a and c inclusive and the
    // second character is a null byte (the end of the string).
    if ('a' <= argv[1][0] && argv[1][0] <= 'c' && argv[1][1] == 0) {
        printf("Success\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failure\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
#include <usual.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char in;
    in=*argv[1];

    if ( in == 'a' || in =='b' || in == 'c') printf("Success\n");
        else
        printf("Failure\n");

}
```